# HTML Not Showing in Webview

Tags: android

I am trying to display some HTML in a webview within a fragment and it is not showing up. I used the same code in a different application and it works but it's not working in this case. I am at a loss. I'm not getting any errors, the HTML is just not displayed. I can see that the webview is appearing. The following is my fragment, layout file, and activity utilizing the fragment.

```
package com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.wirefragments;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link GrommetFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class GrommetFragment extends BaseWireFragment {

    private static final String TITLE_KEY = "title_key";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_KEY = "description_key";
    private static final String WEBVIEW_KEY = "webview_key";



    public static GrommetFragment newInstance(String title, String description, String webView) {
        GrommetFragment fragment = new GrommetFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(TITLE_KEY, title);
        args.putString(DESCRIPTION_KEY, description);
        args.putString(WEBVIEW_KEY, webView);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grommet_fragment, container, false);

        if(getArguments() != null){
            final TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            textView.setText(getArguments().getString(TITLE_KEY,""));

            final TextView description = view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            description.setText(getArguments().getString(DESCRIPTION_KEY, ""));

            WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            String unencodedHtml = getArguments().getString(WEBVIEW_KEY, "");
            String encodedHtml = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(unencodedHtml.getBytes());
            webView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
            webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".wirefragments.GrommetFragment">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="296dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="640dp"
        android:layout_height="67dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="63dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

```
package com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.R;
import com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.ui.BaseActivity;
import com.siemens.glass.ui.GlassGestureDetector;
import com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.wirefragments.BaseWireFragment;
import com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.wirefragments.GrommetFragment;
import com.siemens.google_glass_ict21_app.wirefragments.LocateConnectorFragment;

import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TemporaryPlaceHolderCardsActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private List<BaseWireFragment> wireCards = new ArrayList<>();
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    final ScreenSlidePagerAdapter screenSlidePagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_layout);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(screenSlidePagerAdapter);

        wireCards.add(GrommetFragment.newInstance("Grommet:", "xyz", "<a href='https://svgshare.com/s/YLZ' ><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/YLZ.svg' title='' /></a>"));
        //wireCards.add(LocateConnectorFragment.newInstance("Grommet:", "<a href='https://svgshare.com/s/Z8d' ><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/Z8d.svg' title='' /></a>", "<a href='https://svgshare.com/s/Z8d' ><img src='https://svgshare.com/i/Z8d.svg' title='' /></a>"));

        screenSlidePagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        final TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.page_indicator);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);
    }



    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return wireCards.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return wireCards.size();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onGesture(GlassGestureDetector.Gesture gesture) {
        switch (gesture) {
            case TAP:
                return true;
            case TWO_FINGER_SWIPE_DOWN:
                finish();
            case SWIPE_DOWN:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onGesture(gesture);
        }
    }
}
```